# Changing background color for TableRows when pressed

Tags: android, xml, tablerow

I created an `xml-file` (drawable) for my TableRow layout, which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#03114e" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#2f6699" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#829fbc" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#17456b" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="6dp"
                android:top="6dp"
                android:right="6dp"
                android:bottom="6dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

It's actually supposed to change the background of the TableRow when the user touches it. Unfortunately, nothing happens.
The default background (defined between the second `item`-tag) works perfectly well. However, the `state_pressed` argument has no use.
I even tried `state_focused`,  but still without use.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can't put `<shape>` inside `<item>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList). You have to make the shapes separate drawables and define your `selector` drawable like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/table_row_pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/table_row_default" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Hm, this is weird, since it always worked for Buttons. But not for TableRows.

Comment: @TobiasBaumeister For me it has always worked only like I showed.

Comment: Alright, I used your code now and created the two files `table_row_pressed` and `table_row_default`. In these two files I used the `item`-tag to wrap my solid, stroke, corners & padding. However, now when I open the activity, I get this error: `InflateException - Binary XML file #56`

Comment: Nevermind, my fault. I realized that I don't even have to use the ìtem`-tag, since it's already wrapped by the `shape` tags. Thank you!